# RESTserver. Cannot find REST_controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and Phils REST server but I am getting an error on my remote server. It works fine on my local server.

I am using a subdomain, api.example.com and PHP version 5.3.8.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require(application/libraries/REST_Controller.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/users.php

Line Number: 18
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|files|css|documentation|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE**

I resolved it. Turned out to be a case problem.

Comment: Could you create an answer and accept it, so this will be removed from the unanswered lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. Turned out to be a case problem.